# Compose desktop can't detect horizontal scrolling

Tags: compose-desktop

so i'm developing a desktop application using compose desktop and I need to detect horizontal scroll.

here is what I tried already:

```
  .onPointerEvent(PointerEventType.Scroll) { println(it.changes.first().scrollDelta)}
```

the problem is i can only get vertical scrolls!
how can I detect horizontal scroll event?

by the way by horizontal scroll I mean scrolling with touchpad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get horizontal scroll changes use `x` axis in `scrollDelta`:

```kotlin
.onPointerEvent(PointerEventType.Scroll) { 
   val scrollDelta = it.changes.fold(Offset.Zero) { acc, c -> acc + c.scrollDelta }
   println(scrollDelta.x) 
}
```

Note: it is needed to fold all `changes`, otherwise some scroll deltas can be skipped.

Also, you can use `horizontalScroll` modifier to make a component horizontally scrollable automatically.

```kotlin
val scrollState = remember { ScrollState(initial = 0) }
Box(modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp).horizontalScroll(scrollState)) {
  Text("Scrollable".repeat(20))
}

LaunchedEffect(scrollState.value) {
  println(scrollState.value)
}
```

Comment: with your first solution I wasnt abale to detect horizontal scrolling.
and with your second solution I want to get raw events of scrolling so I dont have a list to scroll

Comment: Can you please provide a small example, where this scrolling is not detected, may be some other components consume scroll event?

Comment: you can read it in this issue
https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/issues/2956#event-8919406084